# How to block the range like 155.155.64.0 - 155.155.127.255 in the form of one string?

Tags: networking, geolocation, range, ip

I know that I can block the whole range this way.

```
155.155.0.0 - 155.155.255.255 --> 155.155/24
```

But how to do it for the range 155.155.64.0 to 155.155.127.255 ?

Answer (score 0):

for 155.155.0.0 it should look like:

```
155.155.0.0 - 155.155.255.255 --> 155.155/16
```

for 155.155.64.0 it should look exactly the same since it is count of bits taken so:

```
155.155.64/18
```

"count of bits taken":

```
155.155.0.0 = 10011011.10011011.00000000.00000000
```

You took 16 bits that's why /16
For 155.155.64.0
You have:

```
10011011.10011011.01000000.00000000
```

So you took 18 bits rest is free.